# Java count realm results

Tags: java, android, realm

I have a method to do this but I am very aware that there is probably a better way to solve the problem I am having.

See below for my current code, please tell me there is something like `.length()` that I can use.

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

deviceImages = realm.where(UploadImage.class).equalTo("imageableId", device.id).equalTo("title", "Before").findAll();

int count = 1;

for(UploadImage image : deviceImages){
    count++;
}

Log.d("Count:", String.valueOf(count));
```

Comment: What is `deviceImages`?

Comment: Sorry forgot that bit, they are just some realm results

Comment: If it's  `RealmResults` why not just use `size()`?

Comment: Might be because I didn't know about `size()`

Comment: Or in your case `size() + 1` as an empty list seemingly is supposed to return 1.

Comment: No 0 would be fine, if you answer with that I will tick it

Comment: You could use `.count()` instead of `findAll()` if the size is the only thing you need

Comment: Ah just as good thanks

Comment: Since ```.count()``` returns a result by calling ```lazyFindAll().size()``` it doesn't matter that much to use ```.count()``` over ```.findAll().size()```. It may increase code readability though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [EpicPandaForce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2413303/epicpandaforce) if you only need the count:

Change:

```
deviceImages = realm.where(UploadImage.class).equalTo("imageableId", device.id).equalTo("title", "Before").findAll();
```

To:

```
int count = realm.where(UploadImage.class).equalTo("imageableId", device.id).equalTo("title", "Before").count();
```

Or as suggested by [Ben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9379617/ben) if you want to maintain the results variable, use:

```
int count = deviceImages.size();
```